# How I create controller folder in mvc6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

> > I Created empty project in mvc6 but theres is no mvc folders , how i ceate model,view,controller folders ?

Comment: What for, exactly? Folder names aren't special in ASP.NET MVC, you're free to organize your code how you like.

Comment: but if i create new controller folder, when i do right click on folder i am not getting add ->controller

Comment: I believe that's because there is no IDE support for ASP.NET MVC 6 yet.

Comment: when i create exmple project in mvc6 with controllers , it exist there

Answer (score 1):

Because an Aspnet core empty project is truly empty. It is up to you to go about making it.

If you notice it's not just the folder but some of the most used middlewares will also not be there such as app.MVC and app.usemvc in your startup.cs class. The purpose of an empty project is to give you complete control over what you need or don't need.

If you know you definitely need MVC then I suggest you use the ASP.Net MVC template that comes with all the folders and goodies you will need to run MVC.

As for MVC folder structure; controllers and models don't need any special folders. That's just a convention. But views do. So you need to have a Views folder at least.